# Parse json string that carries a collection of objects in actionscript using Json.parse

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am running into an error parsing a json string with  JSON.parse(...)

```
var str:String= '[{"AA":"A1", "BB":"32"}, {"AA":"A2", "BB":"12"}, {"AA":"A3", "BB":"14"}]';
var propertySets:Object = JSON.parse(str);
```

I can tell that I am getting the syntax wrong with constructing the JSON string but I have tried quite a few things before giving up. Any help with how to deal with collections would be great.

The following simple case works for me

```
var str:String= '{"test":"line1"}';
var propertySets:Object = JSON.parse(str);
```

Thank you

Comment: `JSON.parse('[{"AA":"A1", "BB":"32"}, {"AA":"A2", "BB":"12"}, {"AA":"A3", "BB":"14"}]')` works well in JS console

Comment: Can you tell use the error that you are getting? I would say, since this is a list, add a wrapper around the list so after you parse the json you can call propertySets.listOfObjects

Comment: My bad. This works fine all of a sudden. Apologies for the false call; there was something wrong with the project itself in FlashBuilder. Thank you for the help with the JS console bit.

Comment: You should close your question as SO thrives to keep everything answered :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in the JSON string is correct. The way it is formatted will return an Array instance from JSON.parse(). The following code works for me:

```
var str:String = '[{"AA":"A1", "BB":"32"}, {"AA":"A2", "BB":"12"}, {"AA":"A3", "BB":"14"}]';
var propertySets:Array = JSON.parse(str) as Array;

trace(propertySets[0].AA); // prints "A1"
trace(propertySets[0].BB); // prints "32"
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark since I don't know actionscript, but try wrapping the array in an object

```
var str:String= '{"objectArray":[{"AA":"A1", "BB":"32"}, {"AA":"A2", "BB":"12"}, {"AA":"A3","BB":"14"}]}';
```